# How to keep the last tab open in accordion after page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, woocommerce

I created a According store for my store with a link in the title that searches for products. However, is there an option to add a code to this that will open the last opened page before reloading the page? My website - https://www.styl-bruk.eu/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CSS Animated Accordion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".accordion_header").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("active")){
            $(".accordion_header").removeClass("active");
        } else {
               $(".accordion_header").removeClass("active");    
               $(this).addClass("active");
        }
    })
     $(".accordion_header:first").addClass("active");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="accordion_wrap accordion_1">
    <div class="accordion_header">
      <a href="https://www.styl-bruk.eu/jsf/jet-woo-products-grid/tax/product_cat:55/#new">Polbruk</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_body">
     [elementor-template id="12389"]
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="accordion_wrap accordion_2">
    <div class="accordion_header">
      <a href="https://www.styl-bruk.eu/jsf/jet-woo-products-grid/tax/product_cat:55/#new">Bruk-Bet</a>
    </div>
    <div class="accordion_body">
     [elementor-template id="12389"]
    </div>
  </div>

</div>  
<style>
   @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,700&display=swap');

.wrapper{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Muli', sans-serif;
}

.wrapper body{

}

..wrapper{
  width: 500px;
  margin: 80px auto 0;
}


.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 700;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
    background: #54595F;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap:first-child .accordion_header{
  border-top-left-radius: 3px;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap:last-child .accordion_header{
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap:last-child .accordion_header:hover{
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header:before,
.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header:after{
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  right: 15px;
  width: 20px;
  height: 2px;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header:hover{
  color: #fff;
  border-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header:hover:before,
.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header:hover:after{
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header:after{
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_body p{
  padding: 15px;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 22px;
  color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header.active{
  color: #fff; 
  border-color: #fff;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap:last-child .accordion_header.active{
  border-bottom: 2px solid #01645d;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header.active:before,
.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header.active:after{
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header.active:after{
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.wrapper .accordion_wrap .accordion_header.active + .accordion_body{
  height: 180px;
} 
</style>
</body>
</html>
```

I can't find any code that would work this way and I don't know that well.

Comment: Yes, there's an option to do that: write some code. What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, a HTML problem, a PHP problem, or a WooCommerce problem?

Comment: You need to store the state somewhere, including the accordion which was open, and then reload that when the page refreshes. Options might include localstorage in the browser, Session on the server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You should use wp_options to save the selected tab in database.

The process could be as follows:

1- Send Ajax call on expanding the accordion tab.

2- Store the selected tab using `add_option()` function.(This could be element's id or attribute)

3- When page loads you will need a second Ajax call that will get option that you stored above using `get_option()` function.

4- Add the active class to that tab which you get from function.

Note: I suggested using ajax as I'm considering you are doing it via Elementor(Not using template file/backend)